# Como enviar 2 variables a funcion update laravel?

Tags: laravel

necesito nuevamente de su ayuda, he estado intentando enviar 2 variables a traves

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
    @foreach($cierres as $ci)
    <form class="" action="/cierres/[$ci->fecha, $ci->id_cobrador]" method="post">
        @csrf
        @method('PUT')
        <input type="text" name="var1" value="{{$ci->id_cobrador}}">
        <input type="text" name="var2" value="{{$ci->fecha}}">
        <input type="text" name="var3" value="{{$ci->nombre}}">
        {{$ci->activo}}
        <button type="submit" name="button">Enviar</button>
        </form>
    @endforeach
@endsection
```

al hacerlo de esta forma me dice que:

```
ArgumentCountError
Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\CierreController::update(), 2 passed in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/Dropbox/creditos/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Controller.php on line 54 and exactly 3 expected
```

mi update:

```
public function update($fech, $id, Request $request)
    {
        //
        return $request;
    }
```

Pero no se que hacer ya que estoy enviando los parametros que creo convenientes.

Archivo route:

```
Route::resource('cierres','CierreController');
  Route::get('/crear_cierre/{fecha}/{id}', 'CierreController@crear')->name('crearcierre');
```

Comment: Qué tienes declarado en el archivo routes?

Comment: @cooper ya modifique la pregunta, agregue el route en el de resource es como lo estoy intentando hacer y el otro lo cree por si el update no me funcionaba, pero no se por qué el la ruta crear_cierre no me envía los inputs